# SQL Insert: Error checking

Tags: java, sql, message

I have the follow class, the insert function works very well , in so far that you enter the right informations. UserID is a primary key, and i wanna give out some personal error message, when the userID already exsits, or more then 10 signs.. can somebody explain me how i can check on those two conditions?

```
public void createCustomer(String UserID, String userName, String userMail ) throws SQLException { 

            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            String iSQL = "INSERT INTO TEST_USER" 
                                + "(UserID, UserName, UserMail VALUES"      
                                + "(?, ? ,?)";


            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(iSQL);

            pstmt.setString(1, userID);
            pstmt.setString(2, userName);
            pstmt.setString(3, userMail);

            pstmt.executeUpdate();


}
```

Thanks alot.

Comment: Mind the closing bracket:
...
+ "(UserID, UserName, UserMail) VALUES"      
...

Answer (score 0):

To check for issues, you can use a try catch, and then within the catch, you know that an error has occurred.

```
try {
    // do your sql calls here
} catch (SQLException e) { 
    // handle the sql error here (for instance printing the message)
}
```

You can check for which error using these:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-messages-server.html

you can use the method e.getErrorCode() and equality check against those codes.

Comment: but i dont know which kind of error, how can i filter out which error it is to set the right error message?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can check the length of the userId before

```
if (UserID.length >= 10) {
  // do your error handling
}
```